# Use emacs parser in java?

Tags: java, swing, emacs, rtrt

I found on internet a Parser for emacs here : http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/rtrt-script.el for testRT script (an IBM tool for test).

And I want to know if it's possible to use this Emacs Lips parser File in a Java Swing application. I just need the part who indent the code. For example with a command line like : 
I give the file I need to indent with the rtrt-script.el and in return I have a file with indentation. 
there is any way to do that?
Thank's for your help.

edit :
The part I think I need is between:

Indentation du code.

```lisp
(defun rtrt-script-indent-line ()
  "Indent current line as RTRT-SCRIPT code"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion                ; si la ligne précedente est test ou 

    (beginning-of-line)
    (if (bobp)                          ; Check for rule 1
        (indent-line-to 0)
      (let ((not-indented t)      cur-indent)
        (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*--[ -=]*\n") ; indentation des commentaires
            (progn             
              (save-excursion    ; si la ligne précedente est test ou 
                (forward-line -1)       ; on indente au même niveau.
                (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\<\\(TEST\|SERVICE\\)\\>")
                    (setq cur-indent (current-indentation))
                  (while not-indented
                    (forward-line -1)

                    ;; on ignore les lignes blanches et les commentaires.
                    (while (looking-at "^[ \t]*\n")
                      (forward-line -1))
                    (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\<END\\>") ; Check for rule 3
                        (progn

                          (setq cur-indent (current-indentation))
                          (setq not-indented nil))
                    ; Check for rule 4
                      (if (looking-at 
                           "^[ \t]*\\<\\(ENVIRONMENT\\|ELEMENT\\|INITIALIZATION\\|DEFINE[ \t]+STUB\\|TERMINATION\\|TEST\\|SERVICE\\|NEXT_TEST\\)\\>")
                          (progn
                            (setq cur-indent (+ (current-indentation) rtrt-script-indent))
                            (setq not-indented nil))
                        (if (bobp)      ; Check for rule 5
                            (setq not-indented nil))    
                        ))))
                )
              )
          (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\<\\(END\\|NEXT_TEST\\)\\>") ; Check for rule 2
              (progn
                (save-excursion
                  (forward-line -1)

                  ;; on ignore les lignes blanches.
                  (while (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\(\n\\|--.*\n\\)")
                    (forward-line -1))

                  (setq cur-indent (- (current-indentation) rtrt-script-indent)))
                (if (< cur-indent 0)
                    (setq cur-indent 0)))
            (save-excursion 
              (while not-indented
                (forward-line -1)

                ;; on ignore les lignes blanches et les commentaires.
                (while (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\(\n\\|--.*\n\\)")
                  (forward-line -1))

                (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\\<END\\>") ; Check for rule 3
                    (progn

                      (setq cur-indent (current-indentation))
                      (setq not-indented nil))
                    ; Check for rule 4
                  (if (looking-at 
                       "^[ \t]*\\<\\(ENVIRONMENT\\|ELEMENT\\|INITIALIZATION\\|DEFINE[ \t]+STUB\\|TERMINATION\\|TEST\\|SERVICE\\|NEXT_TEST\\)\\>")
                      (progn
                        (setq cur-indent (+ (current-indentation) rtrt-script-indent))
                        (setq not-indented nil))
                    (if (bobp)          ; Check for rule 5
                        (setq not-indented nil))    
                    ))))
            )
          )
        (if cur-indent
            (progn
              (save-excursion    ; si la ligne précedente est test ou 

                (message "cur_indent =>%d" cur-indent)
                (if (looking-at "^[ \t]*\n")
                    (indent-line-to 0)
                  (indent-line-to cur-indent)
                  ;; tant qu'a faire on retire aussi les tabulations.
                  (untabify (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)))
                )
              )
          (indent-line-to 0)))
      )
    )
  ) ;; If we didn't see an indentation hint, then allow no indentation
```

Comment: The file you linked contains EMACS-Lisp code, apparently implementing EMACS support for a particular file format.  It is not a parser *per se*.  It relies on its host EMACS environment to do its job.  You could possibly use it by launching a scripted EMACS session from Java, but that's kinda heavyweight.  You cannot use it directly in Java.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a lot of file not Indented.  
I want to check all of this file and indent with java. The is script for an IBM software, and does not include a way to indent his script. 
So there is 2 solutions : I find something to do automatically with this emacs script, or I code somethings in java to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
emacs --batch -l /path/to/rtrt-script.el my-file.rtrt \
      -f rtrt-script-mode --eval '(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))' \
      -f save-buffer
```

Note that this will overwrite `my-file.rtrt` with the indented version.

Comment: Thank you, I have a "End of file during parsing" error, I will give it a look on Google.

Comment: Changing simple quote by double quote like this " : emacs tell me : 
indenting region...
indenting region...done.
But the file isn't modified. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell emacs to run code upon startup. See options `-f`, `-l` and `--eval` (and maybe `--batch`, too) in `man emacs`.